# TSQL Group by error with statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'll admit that group by always gives me problems and maybe it's because I don't understand its proper use but hopefully once I see how its done with this, I'' understand more.

My statement:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, A.[endTime]) as [month],
                   MONTH(A.[endTime]) as [monthValue],
                   (
                    SELECT count(employee) as attendees FROM Focus_Attendees WHERE meetingID = A.[id]
                   ) as attendees,
                   (
                    SELECT count(id) as totalMeetings FROM Focus_Meetings WHERE id = A.[id]
                   ) as totalMeetings

            FROM   Focus_Meetings as A
            WHERE YEAR(endTime) = @year
            GROUP BY DATENAME(month, A.[endTime]),  MONTH(A.[endTime])
            FOR XML PATH ('dataSet'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

`Column 'Focus_Meetings.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

I dont want to group the data by ID as then I would have an individual record for each result. My table contains meetings and I am trying to get the total amount of meetings per month and then from that, the number of attendees of those meetings.

Any advice to achieve this by tweaking the statement?

Update:

I changed it to this query:

```
        SELECT DATENAME(month, A.[endTime]) as [month],
               MONTH(A.[endTime]) as [monthValue],
               count(B.[employee]) as totalAttendees
        FROM   Focus_Meetings as A
        JOIN focus_attendees as B
        ON A.[id] = B.[meetingID]
        WHERE YEAR(endTime) = @year

        GROUP BY DATENAME(month, A.[endTime]),  MONTH(A.[endTime])
        FOR XML PATH ('dataSet'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

This returns my XML:

```
`<root>
  <dataSet>
    <month>July</month>
    <monthValue>7</monthValue>
    <totalAttendees>1</totalAttendees>
  </dataSet>
  <dataSet>
    <month>June</month>
    <monthValue>6</monthValue>
    <totalAttendees>13</totalAttendees>
  </dataSet>
</root>`
```

This is correct but I also need the total meetings in that month which would be `count(A.[id])` but that would give me the error

Comment: Do joins to the Focus_Attendees and totalMeetings instead of having them in the select clause

Comment: Does getting rid of the "for xml" clause still give you the same error?

Comment: @TMNT2014 I updated the question with the results from your answer

Comment: @SBB did you see Vulcronos's answer? So if the ids are unique then you could do just add a Count(distinct A.id) to your query. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Joins Instead.

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, A.[endTime]) as [month],
       MONTH(A.[endTime]) as [monthValue],                   
       count(employee) ,
       count(distinct A.[Id]) 

 FROM  Focus_Meetings as A
       LEFT JOIN Focus_Attendees B ON B.meetingID = A.[id]
 WHERE YEAR(A.endTime) = @year
 GROUP BY DATENAME(month, A.[endTime]),  MONTH(A.[endTime])
 FOR XML PATH ('dataSet'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Disclaimer: I have not run the query so might need some minor tweaks.

Comment: This outputs the same value for the counts when in fact they should be different

Comment: Did you use left joins or just JOIN?

Comment: Used your query exactly

Comment: The outcome is correct when I remove `count(C.id) as meetings` but once that is included, its value is the same as `count(employee)`

Comment: Although this is working, there can be more than 1 meeting on the same day that ends at the same time so this wouldn't include that as its looking for only distinct end times :/

Comment: replace count(distinct C.[endTime]) with count(C.[endTime]) should include the duplicates. It will however exclude meetings that have no end. Remember to cater for those poor people stuck in a meeting without end.

Comment: @WelshGandalf the numbers are off when I do this, I believe its adding up both counts or something strange. I have 7 meetings with 13 attendees prior to the count on end time. When i include it, I have 14 meetings and 13 attendees

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are grouping by the date but trying to select a count by id.

The first idea is to wrap the subselects in a SUM so that all the attendees for all meeting within a month will get summed together.

Your statement:

```
SELECT count(id) as totalMeetings FROM Focus_Meetings WHERE id = A.[id]
                   ) as totalMeetings
```

makes no sense.  If id is a primary key, you are joining to yourself and will always get 1.  Just replace that line with count(*) to get the total meetings in a month.